# How to detect when an audio device has been plugged and unplugged?

Tags: c#, audio, plug-and-play

How to detect when an audio device has been plugged and unplugged using C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "audio device" and where it gets pluged in? headphones in chinch for example?

Comment: Here audio device means "audio jack"(that is headphone and speakers),I am inserting my headphone and speaker plug into my system inupt/output devices.

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is probably WMI. You can subscribe to WMI events reflecting the creation/destruction of instances of most WMI classes. An instance of [`Win32_SoundDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exists for each audio device.

If you want details of the status of a specific device (on speakers, muted, ...) then WMI doesn't appear to include this.

YOu'll probably need to use COM interop to access the [MMDevice API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316556%28VS.85%29.aspx) which includes the ability to enumerate "[endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370793%28VS.85%29.aspx)" devices. This will be hard work as there doesn't appear to be a typelib you can import, rather you'll need to either write some C/C++ to provide a proxy or re-create the necessary COM interfaces etc. in .NET manually.